# Cohomology of Lie Groups finite dimensional?

Tags: lie-groups, homology-cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group, without any further assumptions. Is it true, that its rational cohomology ring 
$$H^\bullet(G,\mathbb Q)$$
 is finite dimensional? Is $G$ homotopy equivalent to a compact Lie group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both questions have the answer of "yes".  Of course, an answer of "yes" to the second must imply and answer of "yes" to the first because every compact manifold has a finitely generated cohomology ring.

So, why is $G$ homotopy equivalent to a compact Lie group?  In fact, more is true.  We have the following theorem (see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) for more):

> Suppose $G$ is a connected subgroup.  Then, there exists a maximal compact subgroup $K\subseteq G$.  Further, all such maximal compact subgroups are conjugate and $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$.

(Note that while $G$ is diffeomorphic to $K\times\mathbb{R}^n$, $G$ is only rarely isomorphic (as a group) to a product of $K$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Finally, simply note that $K\times\mathbb{R}^n$ obviously deformation retracts onto $K$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this theorem other then Wikipedia? In fact my question was inspired by reading wikipedia and I wanted to make sure, that it is correct what is written there :)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53080/homotopy-type-of-connected-lie-groups seems to have a good bit of information, as well as more references in it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you say something about the idea of proof that $G=K\times \mathbb R^n$?